# Regular expression for searching a certain sequence in Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse, search

I am trying to write a regular expression in the Eclipse search in order to identify methods that start with "has" within while loops.
I have tried the following regular expression:

```
while(\s|\w)*has(\s|\w)*
```

but this doesn't seem to work.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Will `while.*has` do?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It only takes a single line, but I need my regular expression to span over multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex may help if you don't have any other brackets inside the while. Keep in mind this regex can also freeze.

```
while\s*\((\w|\s|[^{}])*\)\s*\{[^{}]*(has\w+\()+
```

Answer (score 0):

What I was actually searching for was the following regular expression:

```
while(.|\n|\r)*has.*\(\)
```

Thanks Mr. T, actually your answer helped me figure out what I was looking for.

Comment: What an awful pattern, it can freeze the system. Use `while[\s\S]*has.*\(\)` or `while(?s:.*)has.*\(\)`

Comment: You're right, Wiktor, I don't have too much experience with regular expressions, I only checked whether it would match the sequence I was searching for.

Comment: Besides, the `.*` is greedy, are you sure you want to match the rightmost occurrence? If not, use lazy, `*?` / `[\s\S]*?`.